# Solidity. Truffle. Call contract function in migration file

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

Tell me, how through truffle, after the deployment of the contract, call one of its functions? I mean, during migration, how can I call the function of the contract?

```
var Ownable = artifacts.require("./Ownable.sol");

    module.exports = function(deployer) {
        var ownable;
        var ownableAddress;

        deployer.then(async () => {
            ownable = await deployer.deploy(Ownable);

            ownableAddress = ownable.address; 
            await ownableAddress.addContractAdresses(address);
        });
};
```

Here is the function call

```
await ownableAddress.addContractAdresses(contract.address);
```

But I get an error

```
TypeError: ownableAddress.addContractAdresses is not a function
```

Here is the contract itself and its function

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Ownable {

    mapping (address => bool) public authorizedContractAdresses;

    function addContractAdresses(address _address) 
        public
    {
        authorizedContractAdresses[_address] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question, but generally, you call a contract method by using `contract.method.call()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a instance of deployed contract with `await Ownable.deployed()` after deployment. You can achieve what you are looking for with a much simpler looking script.

```
module.exports = async (deployer) => {
    await deployer.deploy(Ownable);
    ownableInstance = await Ownable.deployed();
    await ownableInstance.addContractAdresses(ownableInstance.address);
};
```